# How to test a NodeJS controller with a nested dependency?

Tags: node.js, typescript, unit-testing, express, jestjs

I've got a service that loads a `JSON` from a file:

```
import { promises, existsSync } from "fs";

import { dataPath } from "../../utils";

export const getUsersService = async () => {
  if (!existsSync(dataPath)) {
    console.log("File not found");
  }

  const data = await promises.readFile(dataPath, "utf8");
  return data;
};
```

I then have a controller that is going to be a handler for an `Express` router:

```
export const getUsers = async (
  req: Request,
  res: Response,
  next: NextFunction
) => {
  try {
    const result = await getUsersService();
    const users = JSON.parse(result);

    if (!users) throw new Error("There are no users");

    res.status(200).send(users);
  } catch (err) {
    next(err);
  }
};
```

This controller is used as below:

```
const router = express.Router();

router.get("/", getUsers);
```

In my test file:

```
import { getUsersService } from "../../../../services/users";

// I mock the service since it's not what I want to test but I want to control what gets returned

jest.mock("../../../../services/users");

const mockGetUsersService = getUsersService as jest.Mock;

describe("getUsersController", () => {

  beforeEach(() => {
    jest.clearAllMocks();
  });

  it("responds with a 404 if there is no user", async () => {
    const req = {body: {}, params: {}}
    const res = {
      send: jest.fn(() => res)
      message: jest.fn(() => res)
      status: jest.fn(() => res)
      json: jest.fn(() => res)
  };
    const next = jest.fn();

    mockGetUsersService.mockResolvedValueOnce('fake user');
    const result = await getUsers(req, res, next);

    expect(mockGetUsersService).toBeCalled(); 
      // PASSED

    expect(mockGetUsersService).toHaveBeenCalledWith(null); 
      // FAILED  
      // Expected: null
      // Received: called with 0 arguments

    expect(res.status).toBe(404);
      // FAILED
      // Expected: 404
      //Received: [Function mockConstructor]
  });
});
```

I'll also want to test tat it receives a 200 in case it returns data but I need to figure out first what's wrong with my approach.

Thanks

Comment: where you able to solve this issue ?

Answer (score 0):

You want to use **supertest**: https://www.npmjs.com/package/supertest

Do not mock the Request or Response objects. Just use supertest.

Note: you don't even need to start the express server, just pass it along to the supertest instance.

Comment: I'll use supertest for integration tests but thinking more of a unit test for this one

Comment: For unit testing a controller supertest can work as well, but you need to set your controller into a Express Router. I.e. In the unit test, create an express instance and `use` the controller on the root route. Now make use of supertest to request to the path '/' so the controller is executed. Profit. IMHO you should avoid mocking the Request or Responds objects.